# unity) I deleted the game, but the PlayerPrefs are still there

Tags: unity-game-engine

#### Environment

unity in macOS, macOS game

#### ISSUE

I deleted the game and built a new one. But the PlayerPrefs from the previous game I deleted are still there. How do I clear PlayerPrefs of build file?

#### things I've tried

- `PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll()`

This didn't work the way I wanted it to. This only removed the editor's PlayerPrefs. This did not delete the PlayerPrefs for the build file.

- `Edit → Clear All Player Preferences`

This didn't work the way I wanted it to. This only removed the editor's PlayerPrefs. This did not delete the PlayerPrefs for the build file.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I clear PlayerPrefs of build file?

If you want to delete them you need to delete the file, which is in the Standalone Player storage location.

**For macOS that location would be:**

```cs
~/Library/Preferences/com.ExampleCompanyName.ExampleProductName.plist
```

[PlayerPrefs Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)